# Ideas to encrypt/obfuscate results in a Presto query?

Tags: sql, encryption, obfuscation, presto

Scenario:

1. I have a Presto table that I will be querying and sending
   results to various semi-trusted parties.
2. These semi-trusted parties will analyze the data and return results
   back to me.
3. Some of the data in this table is "semi-private"— nothing that could
   cause real harm if it were discovered, but private nonetheless (like the name of a device).
4. The signature of this "semi-private" data will be important for GROUP BY clauses, but the actual data itself is not important to the semi-trusted parties.
5. When this analyzed data is returned back to me, I'll need to be able to decrypt/de-obfuscate this "semi-private" data in order to act on it.

Question:

**Is anyone familiar with a way to encrypt/obfuscate a column of data purely within a Presto SQL query that can be decrypted/de-obfuscated in a deterministic way later on?**

I know that I could easily post-process the results of the query and encrypt/obfuscate it myself, but I would like to leverage the distributed execution model of Presto if at all possible.

The level of encryption/obfuscation does not need to be impenetrable— just something a bit more complex than base64 encoding it (and preferably with a simple secret).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more research, I stumbled across the [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) which seems possible to implement entirely in a Presto DB query.

I've been able to test it briefly with the following proof-of-concept:

```
WITH

private_data AS (
  SELECT 'some private string' as private
),

encrypted_data AS (
  SELECT
  zip_with(
    regexp_extract_all(private, '.'),
    regexp_extract_all(substr('a27e6f329c03461688d6866203aasdljfasaslksa7982k3lkjsd987fok2jlkj0sdf9c59c', 1, length(private)), '.'),
    (x, y) -> 
      bitwise_xor(codepoint(cast(x as varchar(1))), codepoint(cast(y as varchar(1))))
  ) as encrypted_data
  FROM private_data
),

decrypted_data AS (
  SELECT
  array_join(
    zip_with(
      encrypted_data,
      regexp_extract_all(substr('a27e6f329c03461688d6866203aasdljfasaslksa7982k3lkjsd987fok2jlkj0sdf9c59c', 1, cardinality(encrypted_data)), '.'),
      (x, y) -> 
        chr(bitwise_xor(x, codepoint(cast(y as varchar(1)))))
    ),
    ''
  ) as decrypted_string
  FROM encrypted_data
)

SELECT
*
FROM private_data, encrypted_data, decrypted_data
```

It seems to work, although I would love to simplify it more. Can anyone see ways to optimize it? (For example: casting from a `varchar` with a length of one to a `varchar(1)` seems ridiculous, but it complains if I don't. Also `regexp_extract_all` is the only way I can find to convert a varchar into an array.)

Comment: Did you find this out yourself? Awesome.

Comment: Yep. Found that XOR algorithm and converted the sample python code to something that would work in Presto. Have been using it for a couple of years now and it seems to work really well.

Comment: I got a lot of help from it, indeed. I did however run into some issue which was caused by regexp_extract_all(), for some reason it couldn't "decode" all characters properly. Using `regexp_split(somestring, '') temparray1` in a similar way I got around that - the problem was that the output array had two empty elements, one at the front and one at the end. I could fix that by `slice(temparray1, 2, cardinality(temparray1) - 2) array1 `

Answer (score 0):

I think you could provide your own UDF (User Defined Function) which could do some symmetric encryption. Here you have documentation how you could implement such function: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html, and here you have some example project with Presto UDFs.

Then in Presto you could:

```
SELECT decrypt_your_udf_function(private_column_encrypted, 'your password')FROM table;
INSERT INTO table (private_column_encrypted) SELECT encrypt_your_udf_function(private_column, 'your password') FROM ...
```

Comment: I think that's a good call, but unfortunately I'm using a managed Presto service (AWS Athena) so I don't think I can define UDFs. I need a way to do it entirely within the confines of a SQL statement.

Comment: You are already able to define UDF in AWS Athena (and Lambda). Here an example: [Redacting sensitive information with user-defined functions in Amazon Athena (2020-Nov-10)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/redacting-sensitive-information-with-user-defined-functions-in-amazon-athena/).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample project which has UDF for basic encryption and decryption and you can find it [here](https://github.com/anilkulkarni87/prestoudf). 
Below are some of the ideas:

1. Use AWS KMS to encrypt and decypt the data. For encryption, its better if we can get the KMS key id dynamically rather than providing it as an input or storing in the jar itself.
2. If thats too costly then alternate is develop custom encryption logic and use that in the presto UDF code.